# Ввод строки c++ с пробелами

Tags: c++, строки

Следующая проблема:

`getline` не хочет работать после того как я ввожу некоторое число в другую переменную.
Понятия не имею почему так происходит, в c++ новичок

```
#include <string> 
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    string str;
    cin >> n;
    getline(cin, str);
    cout << str;
}
```

Comment: if (!cin) {
        std::cerr << "не смог прочитать число";        
    }
    else {
        std::getline(cin, str);
        cout << str;
    }

Answer (score 1):

`getline` дочитывает остаток первой строки, все что идет после числа. Даже если там ничего нет, кроме символа переноса строки.

Например, если ввести `1,2`, то в `getline` попадет `,2`.

Возможных решений несколько:

- Вызвать `getline` два раза. Первый раз проверить, что получилась пустая строка, и если нет, выдать ошибку, что в первой строке после числа мусор. А результат второго вызова уже использовать.
- Проигноировать оставшуюся часть первой строки, вот так: `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');`.